# In plesk 9.3.0, which php.ini is in use?

Tags: php, memory

I have 3 (actually 4, but the 4th one is for installatron) php.ini files in my Virtuozzo Container running RHEL 5.x

```
/vz/root/1003/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/php.ini
/vz/root/1003/etc/php.ini
/vz/root/1003/etc/etc/php.ini
```

which one do I use to change the MEMORY_LIMIT for a wordpress app running in the container 1003?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to tell is to call [phpinfo()](http://php.net/phpinfo) from a page in your application's docroot.